# Trying to load java applet via html file

Tags: java, html, applet, localhost

Directory is like so:

```
test.html
blah
hmmm
```

Inside "blah" we have all the applet files, including blahBlah.class. Inside "hmmm" are a few more more class files that were taken from a library or something, they are used by the project also.

I write in test.html...

```
<applet name="blah" code="/blahBlah.class" codebase="blah"></applet>
```

(along with every other variation I could think of)

Farthest I've gotten is:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: blahBlah (wrong name: blah/blahBlah)
```

Now inside blahBlah.java, we have:

```
package blah;
```

I'm not sure if it's related.

Also wondering if it may be necessary to place the project in a jar file and set the archive attribute of the applet?

The real files are not blah and blahBlah, but I've replaced the names faithfully.

Comment: @Downvoter: ignorance about applets is not a valid downvote reason. This is a perfectly clear and valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: blahBlah (wrong name: blah/blahBlah)

This basically means that it's been executed as

```
java blahBlah
```

instead of

```
java blah.blahBlah
```

In other words, your `code` attribtue is wrong. It has to be

```html
<applet name="blah" code="blah/blahBlah.class" />
```

or just by FQN (see also Andrew's comment)

```html
<applet name="blah" code="blah.blahBlah" />
```

The `codebase` defaults to the current folder, which is fine in this case, so it's removed. An alternative is to put it in *another* folder, such as `/applet` or something. You should at least not use a package folder as code base, but instead the package root.

Comment: Thanks a ton. This works and furthermore it's working to serve it via server, my original intent.

Comment: `blah/blahBlah.class` might be tolerated, but `blah.blahBlah` (the FQN) is correct.

Comment: @Andrew: AFAIK that only works if it's supplied by a JAR archive. OP has the class plain in public domain. You should then really need to specify the URI in `code`. If it were packaged in a JAR, then `<applet archive="Blah.jar" code="blah.blahBlah">` is indeed the only way.

Comment: *"that only works if it's supplied by a JAR archive."*  A quick test indicates it works without a Jar.  I'd be happy to prove it to you on a separate question, but if you'll take my word for it and edit the answer, I'll just up-vote & leave it be.  It concerns me that someone as helpful as you is advising that tired old form of the code attribute repeated in many of the applet elements seen in Sun tutorials (which is where this fallacy originates, I expect).

Comment: @Andrew: fair point. It's been a pretty long time ago I fiddled with an applet for the last time :)

Comment: It seems typical that people helping on applets have themselves not used them in a long time.  (I suspect that says something about applets, but won't go into it here)  :(  I like to keep an eye on the answers coming from the 'regulars', to check they are updated on new developments etc.  And FWIW, thanks for all your assistance to people with applet challenges. :)

Comment: @Andrew: I really appreciate your correction. You probably already know, I always strive to answer as correct as possible. I'll keep this in mind for future applet questions, no problem.